# Fuga de memoria en aplicación desarrollada en VB.net

Tags: vb.net, out-of-memory-error

[image: Incremento De Memoria]

La memoria continua creciendo de a poquito y luego de un tiempo aproximado de 6 horas sale el error `OutOfMemoryException`.

Uso el siguiente método para pasar los datos que recibo en el evento `SerialPort1_DataReceived` y considero que tal vez ese puede ser el problema.

Cualquier ayuda de antemano les agradezco. Si necesitan mas detalles para poder ayudarme háganme lo saber.

```
 Private Sub SetText1(ByVal [text] As String)
         If Me.TextBox1.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim l As New ContextCallback(AddressOf SetText1)
        Me.Invoke(l, New Object() {[text]})

    Else
        Me.TextBox1.Text = [text]

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: porque piensas que el problema esta ahi?

Comment: Porque cuando utilizo las herramientas de diagnostico de visual y tomo instantáneas de la memoria y veo la diferencia entre una y otra veo que en primer lugar aparece como la característica que mas crece "Execution Contest" luego despliego la caracteristica mencionada y aparece que lo que hace crecer la memoria es lo siguiente: "QueueUserWorkItemCallback" y asumo que eso se produce porque uso el ContextCallBack.

Comment: no sera la cadena de texto? la estas pasando por valor, o sea la copias...

Comment: No entendí aquello. Voy a tratar de explicar lo que hago. Imagina que me llega un dato del puerto serie. En ese punto yo uso esto " SetText1(data)" para mostrar el dato en una caja de texto. Pero en el metodo SetText1 acabo de notar que si lleva en la definición lo siguiente: "Private Sub SetText1(ByVal [text] As String)". El ByVal es por valor. Así que asumo que eso es lo que me intentas decir que debo cambiar?

Comment: no se que tamaño sea tu cadena de texto. pero al pasarla por valor hace una copia de la misma. los strings son costosos para la memoria, entonces puede ser el problema?

Comment: El tamaño de cada cadena de texto es de 3 digitos por ejemplo: "119". Y si no debo pasarla por valor como debo pasarla?

Answer (score 0):

puedes emplear una libreria/funcion que libere memoria:

```
Module Utilidades

    Private Declare Auto Function SetProcessWorkingSetSize Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal procHandle As IntPtr, ByVal min As Int32, ByVal max As Int32) As Boolean

    Public Sub LiberarMemoria()

     Try

      Dim memoria As Process
      memoria = Process.GetCurrentProcess()
      SetProcessWorkingSetSize(memoria.Handle, -1, -1)

     Catch ex As Exception

     End Try

    End Sub

End Module
```

[Link](http://www.qualityinfosolutions.com/funcion-para-liberar-memoria-no-utilizada-en-vb-net/)

Te sugiero que agregues mas control sobre el dimensionamiento de variables, y que al mismo tiempo compruebes los datos, sigue las buenas practicas y controles de datos, esto te ayudara a reducir el impacto sobre la memoria..

Comment: Permiteme pruebo haber si se soluciona mi inconveniente. Muchas gracias!

Comment: No he tenido suerte! Aun implementando aquello con lo que me has indicado veo que las fotos instantáneas de la memoria continúan en aumento.

Comment: tambien esta este otro enlace en ingles: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19720171/4717133

Comment: Gracias por el aporte. Intente ver el link pero no hay información. Use lo poco que pude ver de las ayudas ahí expuestas y tampoco me ha ayudado a solucionar el problema. Espero encontrar la solución pronto.

Comment: tendrías que ver si es algún problema en la optimización del código, o no estas usando la mejor manera de manejo de variables.

Comment: puedes verificar que este valor If Me.TextBox1.InvokeRequired Then no este vacio antes de Dim l As New ContextCallback(AddressOf SetText1)

Comment: Déjame ver si entendí bien. La idea es que verifique que el valor de "Me.TextBox1.InvokeRequired" este vació para proceder a dimensionar uno nuevo cierto?

Comment: es correcto, por que hay lo dimencionas sin verificar, una manera de controlar la memoria es verificar tener los datos correcto o esperados antes de iniciar un proceso o tratamiento de datos. esto te ahorra memoria.

Comment: es mas puedes construir una librería que haga estas verificaciones en funciones por separadas y revise los datos antes de iniciar un proceso. esto mejoraría la gestión de memoria.

Comment: y te permite en tal caso que no recibieras un dato o el dato no corresponde a lo esperado guardar en log un error de datos o generar un error por pantalla de datos no esperados o faltante dependiendo de la situación.

Comment: lo otro seria destruir todas las variables/arrays/cosntantes al finalizar cada ciclo o proceso o ejecución.

Comment: Voy a intentar lo que mencionas. Luego te comento como me fue! Muchas gracias! ;)